# Automatic Transfer of Token in Solidity Contract

Tags: token, transfer, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm brand new to Solidity, and I completed a tutorial to create my own token.

Is there a way to automatically transfer my tokens to specified addresses at some time interval?  In other words...

What code should I add to the contract that will transfer 100 tokens to wallet address 0x... once a day forever into the future?

I used the code at the Ethereum Foundation's website: https://www.ethereum.org/greeter

Comment: Here's the correct link to the code I used: [link](https://www.ethereum.org/token)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smart contracts need to be called, they can't start a transaction by themselves.

You can add a function that can be called once a day giving 100 tokens to a wallet.
(Use "now" to get the timestamp and verify it hasn't been called today)
But you will need to make a transaction calling this function each day.

Comment: Note that if you don't want to have to initiate calls yourself you can use this http://www.ethereum-alarm-clock.com/ .